# How can I create an angularJS app without using a seed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angular-seed

From my understanding, this is probably the best way to make an angularJS app: clone this repo https://github.com/angular/angular-seed and then change what you need. However, how would you make an Angular app completely from scratch? I would like it to get it to the state where I can just add app.js/script.js and index.html and just start coding. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: @NathanP. For that one, you start off with even more (the phonecat app)

Comment: @element_j, please see my answer below. No seed, just a couple of files.

Answer (score 0):

On [http://angularjs.org](https://angularjs.org) the "Add Some Control" topic is probably the smallest working example of AngularJS. Start with that, and add more as you need it.
You don't need Bower or NPM, but using it will help you add dependencies faster.

If this is for new development, you might want to check out [Angular](https://angular.io/) rather than AngularJS. AngularJS is kind of *old school* by now.